# Как получить файлы последнего локального-коммита?

Tags: git, git-bash

Суть сделал коммит, хочу получить с сохранением иерархии директорий изменённые коммитом файлы

Скрипт я собственно написал:

> git log -1 --pretty=format:"%h" | xargs -I %id% git diff-tree
>   --no-commit-id --name-only -r %id% | xargs -I %1 dirname %1 | uniq | xargs -I %1 mkdir -p upd/%1 && git log -1 --pretty=format:"%h" | xargs
>   -I %id% git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r %id% | xargs -I % cp % upd/%

Но выглядит он немного монструозно
Было бы замечательно, если привычные к консоли товарищи помогли мне сократить выражение

---

PS: вполне приемлемо вынести как алиас в .git/config, чтобы всю операцию делать по команде git last, или типа того, но в этом тоже нужна помощь )

PPS: только локальные файлы текущего бранча

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> хочу получить с сохранением иерархии директорий изменённые коммитом
>   файлы

```
git show --pretty="format:" --name-only HEAD | xargs -I % cp --parents % upd/
```

Но в изначальном скрипте была возможность указать сколько последних коммитов необходимо учитывать, потому прихожу вот к таком скрипту:

```
git log -1 --pretty=format:"%h" | xargs -I %id% git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r %id% | xargs -I % cp --parents % upd/
```

Если вместо `git log -1` написать `git log -5`, то будут учтены последние 5 поммитов

Answer (score 1):

Есть способ куда короче:

```
git show --pretty="format:" --name-only HEAD
```

Comment: Спасибо за наводку конечный скрипт см. в ответе